# Would it be possible to create a feature to fix compound-word tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

While perusing the data in the latest data dump, I noticed a strange tag, namely "side".  I thought, this tag is very odd, what possible meaning could it have.  Turns out that all the posts tagged "side" were also tagged with "client" or "server", or a couple "scroller".  I've since fixed them all, but would it be possible to create a feature that if somebody tagged something "client" and "side" to automatically correct that as "client-side".  I'm now sure how feasible it would be to search all the compound-word tags and figure out if any of them applied to the tags the user typed in.  It seems like it should be do-able for the most part.  I'm not sure how many people this would help out, but as a reference point, there's 133 posts that are tagged "web" and "services" and there is also a "web-services" tag with 11619 posts.  Most (all?) of the 133 posts with both tags probably belong under the web-services tag.  Not something that's seriously needed, but may help to keep the tags a little neater and more accurate.

Comment: Sadly, most of the ability to do this went out the window when tags were auto-ordered by popularity. I was pretty upset about that change for this very reason, but I do like the benefits of the ordering as well.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148180/can-the-tag-parser-get-smarter-about-spaces