# Can the tag parser get smarter about spaces?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Imagine a world where the following tags exist: [com](/questions/tagged/com) [interop](/questions/tagged/interop) [com-interop](/questions/tagged/com-interop).

Now imagine I ask a question and in the tags list I type `com interop`.

Today, that results in a question tagged [com](/questions/tagged/com) [interop](/questions/tagged/interop)

But what would be cool is if it resulted in a question tagged [com-interop](/questions/tagged/com-interop)

Another obvious application would be preventing [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) [2010](/questions/tagged/2010) and the like.

Does this matter? I think it does. I'm trying to solve a com interop problem today and the huge quantity of [com](/questions/tagged/com) [interop](/questions/tagged/interop) questions out there are making me mental. That is not a correct tagging. If a question is tagged both [com](/questions/tagged/com) and [interop](/questions/tagged/interop) it's because it's about COM Interop and the OP didn't know about the [com-interop](/questions/tagged/com-interop) tag. This means that my searches are much harder than they need to be. I recall we've had a lot of retagging posses looking for tags like [2010](/questions/tagged/2010) and [7](/questions/tagged/7), created when people tried to type entire product names including version suffixes.

If anyone can think of an X and a Y that meet these conditions:

- X, Y, and X-Y are tags already
- a question tagged X and Y should not be tagged X-Y
- a person might be interested in  X or Y, but never in X-Y so this retagging would cause them to miss it

Then by all means add those as an answer. It's my contention that no such combination exists

Comment: And what if I want to tag a question [com] [interop]?

Comment: You could type **interop com** for one thing, but in fact that is a terrible thing to tag a question, just as [visual-studio] and [2010] is wrong.

Comment: Well, your assumption is that they are valid tags on their own. And there could be a possibility they are valid tags under a single post. I don't think we should start making such assumptions about tag validity and I certainly don't want to have to start switching tag order just to be able to post something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add detection/warning of and tools for removal/reversal of sub-string tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132756/add-detection-warning-of-and-tools-for-removal-reversal-of-sub-string-tags)